# If I have multiple forms in one application how can I smoothly transition between them?

Tags: c#, transition, smoothing

If I want to smoothly switch between forms (i.e the sliding transition from 
Microsoft PowerPoint), how can I do this? I am working with Visual Studios 
C#.

Comment: That is if I include in a button that allow the user to 
go back and go forward.

Comment: The `forms` tag is meaningless, as are most of the other tags here.  Is this Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms, or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with WPF, you can put them in a single Panel or Canvas, and apply/update continuously something to the "RenderTransform" property of the Panel/Canvas containing each.  So,

```
        Transform t = new TranslateTransform(0.0f, 0.0f);
        panelA.RenderTransform = t;
        panelB.RenderTransform = t;
```

Then with your favorite timing method, update t slightly each tick.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways (baked XAML animations, etc.) but I'm pretty shaky on giving advice with those, as I'm not quite sure on how to make them work myself. =)